# Use awk replace string by multiplication

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script that when I finally pipe to

```
awk -F'[()]' '{
printf("%s %s\n", $2, $4)
}'
```

returns

```
251.393GB 103.005GB
245.296GB 101.992GB
250.526GB 103.639GB
259.158GB 112.549GB
245.266GB 102.415GB
325.020GB 129.041GB
245.135GB 102.086GB
250.583GB 103.758GB
244.247GB 103.268GB
251.256GB 104.008GB
244.496GB 102.643GB
265.133GB 113.523GB
250.332GB 103.556GB
319.579GB 127.401GB
250.140GB 103.722GB
244.765GB 102.541GB
```

However, I would like to convert `GB` (which I have found acts as 1024^3) to `MB` (which I would like to express as 1000^2).

Using `awk`, how can I detect the unit (`GB`, `MB`, etc.) and convert it to the appropriate related unit using 1000 instead of 1024? In essence I would like to simply treat `GB` as `*(1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000)`

Comment: If you want a script to detect MB, why wouldn't you include MBs in your sample input? Also include the expected output given your posted sample input (which should be reduced to just a couple of lines).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
251.393GB 103.005GB
245.296GB 101.992GB
250.526GB 103.639GB

$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%sMB%s", $i * ($i~/GB/ ? 1073.4 : 1), (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' file
269845MB 110566MB
263301MB 109478MB
268915MB 111246MB
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%.3fMB%s", $i * ($i~/GB/ ? 1073.4 : 1), (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' file
269845.246MB 110565.567MB
263300.726MB 109478.213MB
268914.608MB 111246.103MB
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `perl` where the `e` flag comes handy in such cases

```
$ cat ip.txt 
251.393GB 103.005GB
245.296GB 101.992GB
250.526GB 103.639GB
```

Without limiting decimal precision

```
$ perl -pe 's|([0-9.]+)GB|$1*(1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000)|ge' ip.txt 
269931.178360832 110600.77658112
263384.574459904 109513.076113408
269000.244199424 111281.528897536
```

With precision

```
$ perl -pe 's|([0-9.]+)GB|sprintf "%.3f",$1*(1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000)|ge' ip.txt 
269931.178 110600.777
263384.574 109513.076
269000.244 111281.529
```

Pre-calculating factor

```
$ perl -pe 'BEGIN{$m=(1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000)} s|([0-9.]+)GB|sprintf "%.3f",$1*$m|ge' ip.txt
269931.178 110600.777
263384.574 109513.076
269000.244 111281.529
```

To print `MB` in output as well, use `%.3fMB`

Answer (score 0):

first, precalculate the multiplier:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print (1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000)}'
1073.74
```

then find fields with "GB", multiply them, and append "MB".

```
awk '{
  if($1~"GB") $1=1073.74*$1"MB"
  if($2~"GB") $2=1073.74*$2"MB"
  print $1, $2
}'
```

(both GNU `awk` and `awk` handle math on strings by only considering the number characters, e.g., `"123.45GB" * 10` yields `1234.5`)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
echo "319.579GB 127.401GB" \
| awk '{sub(/GB$/,"",$1);sub(/GB$/,"",$2);printf("%.3f\t%.3f\n", $1*(1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000) , $2*(1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000))}'
```

**output**

```
43145.338      136795.782
```

The same for a file

```
awk '{sub(/GB$/,"",$1);sub(/GB$/,"",$2)
  printf("%.3f\t%.3f\n", $1*(1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000) , $2*(1024*1024*1024)/(1000*1000))}'  file
```

---

You can adjust the decimal precision but changing the `.3` value, or leave it off altogehter if you just want an integer value.

`sub(...)` works by matching `GB` at the end of the line `$`,  and replaces with empty string (`""`) for the named column (i.e. `$1` or `$2`). `sub` will accept any string value in the 3rd field, so "strGB", `arr[1]`, arr[key]` and others will work also.

Comment: That output is missing 300000 MBs.

Comment: OP also wants to detect units; this answer assumes it's always GB.

Comment: I assume the OP is a big boy and can extrapolate from this solution what to do for MB, PB, KB , etc . ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: Without example output from OP, I found the requirement "which I would like to express as 1000^2" to indicate that MB wasn't required. Good luck to all.